# Get Time Object at Start of Day in a Particular Time Zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, date, activesupport

How can I get a ruby Time object that represents the start of the day on a particular date in a given timezone.

Comment: Just a comment as I don't know anything about Ruby's time zone handling: midnight doesn't always exist, and it might occur twice. Brazil changes its clocks at midnight, for example. You should probably find the start of the day, instead.

Comment: Interesting point. For my purposes the start of the day is what I'm interested in. Thank Jon. I'll update the question.

Comment: What is your actual use case? (I found this question because I wanted to get the most recent midnight in California, as UTC, for API quota tracking.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using the `#local` method on the `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` object passing components of the `Date` object.

```
# Get example date and time zone...
date = Date.today
timezone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone['America/New_York']

# Get beginning of day for date in timezone
timezone.local(date.year, date.month, date.day)
```

Answer (score 31):

```
date = Date.today

date.to_time.in_time_zone('America/New_York').beginning_of_day
```

Currently outputs => 2011-11-02 00:00:00 -0400

```
Time.now.in_time_zone('Asia/Shanghai').beginning_of_day
```

Currently outputs => 2011-11-03 00:00:00 +0800

```
date = Date.today

date.to_time.in_time_zone('Asia/Shanghai').beginning_of_day
```

Currently outputs => 2011-11-02 00:00:00 +0800

Comment: I wish it were that simple. Unfortunately, there is no guarantee that the time you arrive at, after the timezone conversion, is in the same day. Sometimes it will be and sometimes it won't depending on the starting and ending zone. I suppose I could compare the date component after the conversion with the original value and adjust if necessary but that's really clunky. What I'd hope for is an elegant way to do it that always works. Hopefully there is something in the api, I don't think this is a crazy thing to want to do.

Comment: I might not understand completely what you're trying to do but `date.to_time.in_time_zone('TIMEZONE').beginning_of_day` gives you 00:00:00 UTC for the original specified date.

Comment: It's doesn't give you 0 UTC, it gives you 0 in the timezone, which is preferable. But, it doesn't do this before converting timezones with in_time_zone so the date is not necessarily valid anymore. Here's in example of what I mean. `date.to_time.in_time_zone('Asia/Shanghai').midnight.in_time_zone(Time.zone).midnight #=> One day in the past.`. Ideally, ruby should allow me to do something like this. `date.to_time(zone)`.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this helps, but this gets me the time at which my Google API quotas reset:

```
# The most recent midnight in California in UTC time
def last_california_midnight
  (Time.now.utc - 7.hours).midnight + 7.hours
end
```

I use it like this with Mongoid, for example:

```
def api_calls_today
  Call.where(updated_at: { '$gte' => last_california_midnight }).count
end
```

This will work no matter what timezone the code is deployed to, as long Mongo is set to UTC.

Answer (score 1):

To get specific day, e.g. `1/2/2021` (day: 1, month: 2, year: 2021)

```rb
("1/2/2021").to_time.in_time_zone('Asia/Shanghai').beginning_of_day
#=> Mon, 01 Feb 2021 00:00:00.000000000 CST +08:00
```

To get current day

```rb
Time.zone = 'Asia/Shanghai'
Time.current.beginning_of_day
#=> Mon, 12 Jul 2021 00:00:00.000000000 CST +08:00
```

I always refer to time, not date because it's pretty sure that I've got the correct output in desired timezone since start.

Notice that these 2 ways provide you the same format result. So you can use it on your further time difference calculation

I prefer using `Time.current` over `Time.now` when define timezone, which can make sure that time is in the timezone you want. Anyway, please always check the result in Rails Console before using it.